Chrome Extension: Communicating Custom Events from Content Script to React/Next.js Application
I'm developing a Chrome extension that needs to send custom events triggered on the YouTube watch page (e.g., when a video ends) to a React/Next.js web application running on a different domain (localhost during development). The event should trigger specific actions within the web app.
My content script is successfully injected into the YouTube watch page, and I'm able to detect the events I need. However, I'm having a hard time sending these events back to my web app.
I've tried using window.postMessage directly from the content script like this:
window.postMessage({ action: 'videoEnded', videoId }, '*');

and then trying to capture it on my React component with:
useEffect(() => {
    const messageListener = (event) => {
      if (event.origin === 'https://www.youtube.com') { 
        if (event.data.action === 'videoEnded') {
          console.log('Video ended in YouTube!'); 
        }
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('message', messageListener);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('message', messageListener);
    };
  }, []);

but nothing it's happening. I'm guessing window object in the content script and the window object in my React app are isolated or there's some sort of cross-origin security policy.
I've also tried using the Chrome Extension Messaging API (chrome.runtime.sendMessage and chrome.tabs.sendMessage), but that only works in the context of the extension and there's no way to use those APIs within a standard React application.
How can I achieve this cross-origin communication between a Chrome extension content script running on the YouTube watch page and a React/Next.js web app?

Your web app runs on a different domain which means it can't be the same window. It can only be another tab or an iframe inside the youtube page. Which is it?

So if the Chrome Extensions opens a hidden iframe to my webapp inside the YouTube watch page I could potentially send messages using .postMessage to my main app? Anyway, too complicated. I'm going with a different strategy.

You can also do it inside the offscreen document and communicate via externally_connectable.

Yes, window.postMessage will not work because the context script and your web application are working in different contexts, but you can setup communication between them via WebSocket which will act as a bridge between them.
Setup a WebSocket server with Nodejs.
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);

    // Broadcast incoming message to all connected clients
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        client.send(message);
      }
    });
  });
});

Connect Your Web App to WebSocket Server
useEffect(() => {
  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

  ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
    if (message.action === 'videoEnded') {
      console.log('Video ended in YouTube!');
    }
  };

  return () => {
    ws.close();
  };
}, []);

Connect Your Chrome Extension to WebSocket Server
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// Assuming you detect the YouTube event somehow
youtubeVideoPlayer.onended = () => {
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({ action: 'videoEnded', videoId }));
};

